# Is it acceptable to manage large DB manipulations inside Room migration?

Tags: android, android-room

When updading DB is it acceptable to run large code to align the DB to my requirements.
For example, I need to alter the table and change column names. Then I need to get all my data in the DB and check if file is located than update the DB accordingly. I need it happen only once when user updates the app to this Room version.

```
        val MIGRATION_8_9 = object : Migration(8, 9) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE RideEntity RENAME videoPresent TO videoState")

            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val rides = DataBaseHelper.getAllPartsFromDB() //get all data
                rides.forEach {
                    val path = MyApp.appContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)!!.path + "/" + it.name + "/"

                    val file = File(path + VIDEO_FILE).exists()

                    if (file) {
                        it.videoState = 1
                        DataBaseHelper.updateData(it) //set the data
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Where:

```
suspend fun getAllPartsFromDB() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val parts = db.rideDao().getAllParts()
    parts
}
```

Function:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM rideentity ORDER BY time DESC")
fun getAllParts(): List<Parts>
```

So my question, despite this works, is this way acceptable? And if the migrate function called only once when the app DB updated from version X to Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it acceptable to manage large DB manipulations inside Room migration?

Yes. However you may wish to put the update loop inside a transaction.

> And if the migrate function called only once when the app DB updated from version X to Y

Yes it is only called the one time. The Migration(8,9) determines this that is the Migration will only be invoked when the version, as stored in the database header, is 8 and then the version number is set to 9.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what do you mean "put the update loop inside a transaction"?

Comment: @Dim when you execute a SQL statement (e.g. updateData method or your ALTER) it is a single transaction, the change is written to disk. So each iteration of your loop is a disk write.  Enclosing the loop in a transactionthen 1 disk write for all.  With SQLiteDatabase you can use `.beingTransaction` etc  before/after.  It's not clear what DatabaseHelper is so couldn't suggest code. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#beginTransaction() (same for SupportSQLiteDatabase).

Comment: @Dim you may wish to read https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html